# How to equip new/crafted weapons in Dead Island Epidemic?

Tags: dead-island-epidemic

In the "ZOMBA"/MOBA of Dead Island, Dead Island Epidemic, you can craft new weapons from blueprints (just like in Dead Island). You go to the workbench, select a blueprint, and if you have the required materials, you can craft a new weapon - which then shows up in your inventory.

But you can click all you like in the inventory, right, left, keyboard - you cannot equip it to your characters. Nor can you from the character screen by clicking on the weapon icons.

So, how does one equip crafted weapons in Dead Island Epidemic?

Comment: -_- this game already dead. . . .

Comment: well, they actively killed it. and it's still lurching around.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the only way to equip weapons is in the Lobby.

Click on "PLAY" on the top, select a game mode and enter the Lobby.
Once the top middle says "IN LOBBY", on the left of the screen you can select the characters.
Inside this menu - and nowhere else - you can equip weapons.

Make sure you are not "Ready" for joining a game, just in the Lobby (check button on lower right).
Click on the two red weapon symbols in the upper left side of the box.
This will open an inventory view where you can either doubleclick or select with a single click and then use the EQUIP button on the lower right side of the screen.